# $f$ measurable iff $f^2$ measurable and $\{f > 0\}$ measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

I know for sure that if $f^2$ is measurable, that doesn't imply that $f$ is measurable, but how does the condition:

$$  \{f > 0\} \text{ measurable }$$

play into making  $f$ automatically measurable?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For $a>0$, we have $\{f>a\} =\{f^2 >a^2\} \cap\{f>0\}$.

Comment: Ohhh, I knew it had to do with a way of rewriting the sets in some sort of way.

Answer (score 1):

**Another Hint**: It holds
$$f  =\sqrt{f^2}1_{\{f>0\}}-\sqrt{f^2}1_{\{f>0\}^c}.
$$